# Recursive Sequence solving for $f(200)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

Let $f$ be defined recursively by: $f(0)=5$ and $f(n+1)=3f(n)-2$. Find $f(200)$

I'm really confused how to go about solving this. Can someone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could think of the first 5 terms as 
$x, \space 3x-2,  \space 9x-8,  \space 27x-26,  \space 81x-80$ where $x=5$ and infer what the equation for the 200th term would be.

ETA: you could think of the terms as $(5), \space 3(5)-2,  \space 9(5)-8,  \space 27(5)-26,  \space 81(5)-80$.  Don't need to add another variable.

Comment: Ok I understand where you got x, and 3x-2 because you replaced f(n) with x but how did you know the next term would be 9x-8? How did you know how much to increase the -2 by?

Comment: $3(3x-2) = 9x-6$ and then i subtracted the other 2.

Comment: alright! Now from there how would I go about finding the 200th term since I am not going to write it all out. Should I try to turn this rule into a submation or induction proof to infer?

Comment: $3x-2$ is term 2

$9x-8$ is term 3

Comment: Sorry, couldn't edit again.  

$3x-2$ is term 2.  $9x-8$ is term 3.  $27x-26$ is term 4.  Can you see the pattern of the coefficient of x?

Comment: no problem. yeah I see that each time the coefficient for x is being multiplied by 3

Comment: $term_n=(3^{n-1})x-(3^{n-1}-1)$ with $n=200$ and $x=5$  Might want to check the first couple of terms. My equation might be off by one.

Comment: what is the coefficient 3^n-1 and not 3^n?

Comment: If we used $3^n$ then the 2nd term would have coefficient of 9 and the 3rd term would have coefficient 27.  But we need them to be 3 and 9.  If you make a table with $n=1,2,3,4...$ at the top and fill in the values underneath it might be more apparent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19053/discussion-between-lil-and-turkeyhundt).

Comment: Adding comment that, yes, i was off by one on my function.  I was thinking the first term was f(1) instead of f(0).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $f_{n+1} - 1 = 3\left(f_n - 1\right)$. Does this help?

Comment: sorry how did you get that statement?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on
OC-Sansoo's answer:

Since
$f(n+1)=3f(n)-2$,
subtracting one from each side,
$f(n+1)-1
=3f(n)-3
=3(f(n)-1)
$.

Letting
$g(n)
=f(n)-1
$,
$g(n+1)
=3g(n)
$.

By induction,
$g(n)
=3^n g(0)
$
or
$f(n)-1
=3^n(f(0)-1)
=4\cdot 3^n
$
or
$f(n)
=4\cdot3^n+1
$.

In general,
if
$f(n+1)
=af(n)+b
$,
we want to find $c$
such that,
if $g(n) = f(n)+c$,
then
$g(n+1) = ag(n)$
(so that
$g(n) = a^n g(0)$).

Since $f(n) = g(n)-c$,
$g(n+1)-c
=a(g(n)-c)+b
=ag(n)-ac+b
$
or
$g(n+1)
=ag(n)+c-ac+b
=ag(n)+c(1-a)+b
$.

If we choose
$c(1-a)+b=0$,
or
$c
=\frac{b}{a-1}
$,
then
$g(n) = a^n g(0)$
or
$f(n)+c = a^n(f(0)+c)$
or
$f(n) 
= a^nf(0)+c(a^n-1)
= a^nf(0)+\frac{b(a^n-1)}{a-1}
$.

Note that does not work if $a=1$,
but then
$f(n)$ is linearly i  ncreasing,
not growing by a power law.